# How to insert where condition in mysql query laravel?

Tags: laravel

I try to insert with code

```
$info = DB::table('role_user')->where('user_id', '=',$current)
->where('role_id', '=',$id)->get();
```

error of insert

```
$response = $info->insert(array('active' => 1));
```

Comment: It is unclear that are you trying to select or insert record?

Comment: insert to role_user table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the update query:

```
$response = DB::table('role_user')
->where('user_id', $current)
->where('role_id', $id)
->update(array('active' => 1));
```

Comment: Tell me how is this any different than mine answer?

Comment: actually, same code. even you described better than me but I tried to make the code little readable and clean.

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert the same `role_user` twice, but you can `update` it

```
$response = DB::table('role_user')->where('user_id', '=',$current)
->where('role_id', '=',$id)->update(array('active' => 1));
```